# Interpretation of yum list results in fedora 21

Tags: fedora, yum

I executed the following command in shell:

```
sudo yum list kernel-core
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Installed Packages
kernel-core.x86_64         3.17.4-301.fc21          @koji-override-0/$releasever
kernel-core.x86_64         3.18.5-201.fc21          @updates
```

The `kernel-core.x86_64` part of version `3.17` is underlined.

Could anyone help me understand what this means? I have already updated all packages using `sudo yum update` and am wondering why I still have the earlier version of kernel-core.

Comment: by default, the latest three kernel versions are kept in fedora in bootable state. so that if you get a non-booting kernel after updating, you can still boot to a previous (known to be working) version.

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting (and colorization) indicates that the 2nd kernel-core package is "newer" than the first and will replace on upgrade.